# Large number division results are not correct

Tags: python, numbers, division

I am running this code:

```
while (zahl != 0):
    buffer = zahl
    rest = zahl%2
    binaryString.append(rest)
    zahl = int(zahl/int(2))
    print("%i / 2 = %i Rest: %i" % (buffer, zahl, rest))
```

For large numbers, for example: 859550836414751812
This code will print following first line:

```
859550836414751812 / 2 = 429775418207375936 Rest: 0
```

This clearly is not correct. I dont know why python is dividing large numbers so poorly.

Whats the matter with large numbers and division? How can I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help in advance

Greetz
r3ngE

Comment: Calling `int` on everything is not how you get integer division.

Comment: So you think the division itself is not written correctly? May I ask you for the correct way?

Comment: `//`. There's probably a dupe around here somewhere.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out that the result is really incorrect... A proper [mcve] that clearly showcases the difference between expected and actual output would be nice.